# Filtering out parts of words in PHP

Tags: php

I've been trying to write something that would remove some parts of the words that are declared as unwanted from users' posts. This is what I came up with:

```
$badWords = array("damn", "hell", "fool"); //we declare an array that will contain all the words we don't want

$txtlower = strtolower($text); //we lowercase the entire text

foreach ($badWords as $word) { //iterate through the array. $word is each bad word respectively

  if (strpos($txtlower, $word) !== false) { //check if the lowercased text contains any bad words (since we lowercased the entire text, it will also lowercase and thus detect all upper or mixed case types of any bad word the user has typed)

    $wordIndex = strpos($txtlower, $word); //get the index of the bad word in the lowercased text. This index will be the same in the original text

    $wordLength = strlen($word); //get the length of the bad word. Now we get back to the original text, i.e. $text

    $typedWord = substr($text, $wordIndex, $wordLength); //this is the original bad word that the user has typed, with the case type intact 

    $replacePart = substr($typedWord, 1, 3); //take the part from the 2nd up to the 5th character of the bad word

    $text = str_replace($replacePart, "...", $text); //replace the $replacePart part with the dots, BUT in the original text, not the lowercased text (important, otherwise it would submit the entire post as lowercase)
  }
}
```

(`$text` is the text the user types in the text box and then submits as a post)

Now this works 99% of time. It removes both the upper and lowercase versions of the words, as well as any mixed type (for example DAmn or fOoL).

The only case where it doesn't work is if the same unwanted word appears more than once in the text. Then it will fix only the first instance of it. So

> Damn, is this DAMn

will become

> D..., is this DAMn

Is there a way to do this, or perhaps some regex solution that would include removing just one part of the word instead of the entire thing?

Thanks!

Comment: @AlivetoDie The code is (inefficiently) case-insensitive.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  `str_replace()` is not case insensitive. I his case `$replacePart = 'amn'`  which is not going to replace `AMn` anyhow

Comment: @AlivetoDie True, but the code begins with lower-casing the entire string.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  but the final replacement done on original text:- `$text = str_replace($replacePart, "...", $text);`  oh you got my point?

Comment: Vlad77 you need to use `$text = str_replace($replacePart, "...", strtolower($text));` (last line)

Comment: Oh so it is. Well, that's unfortunate XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified.

```
$badWords = ["damn","hell","fool"];
$filteredText = preg_replace_callback(
    "(".implode("|",array_map('preg_quote',$badWords)).")i",
    function($match) {
        return $match[0][0] // first letter left as-is
           .str_repeat(".",strlen($match[0])-1); // as many dots as there are letters left
    },
    $text
);
```

**However** please note that word filters like this are an exercise in futility. You cannot be a..ured that innocent words, even a simple greeting like h...o, will be left alone. Sure, you can use word boundaries (`\b`) to only match whole words.

But then there's the issue of people finding bypa..es. I'm sure you've seen them around many forums. Character substitutions can pa$$ right through your filter. Inserting spaces **as s**een here is another way.

My personal favourite is the "Zero Width Space" character, which allows me to type an otherwise filtered word with no apparent difference, defeating the filter entirely.

Humans are creative. Stop them from doing what they want, and they *will* find ways around them. It is, generally, a much better use of time to just say "don't use bad language" in your community's rules, and enlist human moderators to handle the (relatively) rare cases of it occurring.

I hope this helps. You can find more information about this problem in [this informative video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcZdwX4noCE) by Tom Scott.

Comment: Thanks, Niet, that's exactly what I needed! Clean and simple.

I agree with you, it's just for exercise. An in a real-life scenario I'd use it for much more explicit words than those I put here just for an example. Thanks for the link, also :)